# How to handle multiple selected values in a checkbox in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I am new to rails.
I have a model called `Fixture`, where i have an attribute `day`. I want the `day` attribute to store multiple values in array such as day = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]. For this I have used `form_with` and have a checkbox, with multiple options, like Sunday, Monday, Tuesday. This is what my `form_with` looks like.

```
.field
    = f.check_box :day
    = f.label :day, "Sunday"
    = f.check_box :day
    = f.label :day, "Monday"
    = f.check_box :day
    = f.label :day, "Tuesday"
    = f.check_box :day`
```

Can someone tell me the best way that I can approach this problem, and store multiple values in the `day` attribute. Or is there some other easy way around. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: It might help to tag and describe in your question which templating engine you are using (I'm assuming HAML), as this seems to be more of a syntax issue with that than a rails/ruby/form-helpers issue. Although, I may be wrong.

Comment: you can use serialised field

Answer (score 0):

### With Only One Day Selected:

Consider the [select helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select), or the [options for select helper](http://%20https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select).

Here is a quick hack that will help you get started:

```
 <%= f.select(:day, ["Monday", "Tuesday"], :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

I would not use check boxes for this sort of thing. You should be able to use the above and convert it into a haml based syntax. Hope this helps.

Also note that the day attribute must be a string. I am assuming you only want to select one particular day of the week.

### With Multiple Days Selected

#### Quick and Dirty with Boolean:

The quick and dirty approach would be to simply add a boolean field for every day of the week:

`rails g migration AddDaysToFixtures monday:boolean tuesday:boolean wednesday:boolean thursday:boolean friday:boolean saturday:boolean sunday:boolean`

```
.field
    = f.check_box :sunday
    = f.label :day, "Sunday"
    = f.check_box :monday
    = f.label :day, "Monday"
    = f.check_box :tuesday
    = f.label :day, "Tuesday"
```

etc.

#### Has Many through:

The other option could be adding a join table. Using [a has many through relationship](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

#### f.select - selecting multiple

[f.select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) has an option where you can select multiple outcomes. You will have to handle this accordingly in your controller.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the select helper support multi-select? I ask since the OP says, "I want the day attribute to store multiple values".

Comment: No, actually i want to select multiple days of the week. day might have ["Tuesday","Wednesday"]

Comment: @jvillian yes it does, you'll have to add it through the multiple option. see the documentation link above. there are nuances to it, which you should probably be aware of though.